# Assess complexity for Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: python, big-o, complexity-theory, networkx

I am trying to assess the complexity of my python implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm by creating both a loop based and time based big(o) plot.

i understand that from my bid input dataset - which in my case is a CSV. file with three rows: city1, city2, distance, i have to randomly select a series of smaller data sets to run my algorithm on.

how can i randomly select let's say: 5 rows, then 10 rows, 15 rows, 20 rows?

Comment: How are you loading the data into python, have you any preferences for loading it that way? There are lots of options out there, including pandas, numpy etc - if you're using "vanilla" python (i.e. no special modules, perhaps as part of a course), then do you want to load the whole lot into memory, or do you want to pull from the file directly? Is it important to you to potentially pull the same data twice on a second random sample, or do you want to avoid that?

Have you got any code you can share that people can use to help see what you've tried so far? Try posting that.

Comment: I am loading it using networkx. I would like to load the whole graph so i can run it and then i want to randomly select a series of sub-graphs and test how the algorithm's time to run or number of loops it goes through increases with the input data size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.sample`. If you have a list then you can use it like this:

```
import random
rows = [f'city1,city2,{i}\n' for i in range(5)] # equal to f.readlines()

sample_size = 5 # or whatever you need
samples = random.sample(rows, sample_size)

for sample in samples:
    city1, city2, distance = sample.strip().split(',')
    distance = int(distance) # distance is a string because of csv, convert it to a number
    # do your thing here
```

Comment: if i use the code above i get: [('city1', 'city2', 1),
 ('city1', 'city2', 4),
 ('city1', 'city2', 3),
 ('city1', 'city2', 0),
 ('city1', 'city2', 2)]. instead i want actual values for city1, city2 and distances. also if i remove the quotation marks from city1, city2 and add distances instead if i, what i get is the same line five times: for example 'NY' 'LA' 2500

Comment: `rows` should be your input file, I just needed some dummy values. Anyways see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already created a graph from your csv, I'd be tempted to sample directly from your networkx graph.

```
import random    
import networkx as nx
city_graph = nx.complete_graph(20) # generate a sample complete graph to demonstrate on
all_cities = city_graph.nodes()    # a list of all the cities from your graph
sample_size = 5  # make sure this is less than total node-count
sample_population_node_list = random.sample(all_cities, sample_size)
connected_sample_graph = nx.subgraph(city_graph, sample_population_node_list)
```

The [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) module should extract the node-names at random, and then `nx.subgraph` will stitch a new graph together containing that sampling of nodes with any connections carried over from the original graph. There is a similar sampling thing available in [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) that allows you to specify whether you want to sample with replacements or not.

If the original graph is not complete, you may find some combinations result in isolated cities (i.e. if the original is not a complete graph, and if the only way to get to A is via B and B isn't in the sample, and A is, then A will be unreachable). It might be worth running [nx.connected_component_subgraphs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html) on the resultant subgraph to see if it is connected or not.

Also, for completeness, it might be worth comparing your final code to the various algorithms in the [networkx library](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html?highlight=shortest%20paths).